# Density in a topological space.

Tags: general-topology

I have the set $X=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ with topology $T=\{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,c,d\},\{a,b,c,d\}, \{a,b,e\}, X\}$

I want to identify the dense subsets of $X$.

Now, I haven't worked too much with density or limit points, so I sometimes get confused when I have to juggle all the different definitions while doing the problem. So in order to ascertain that I understand these concepts, I'm just going to show my attempt to find one dense subset.

First I note that every point in $X$ different from $a$ is a limit point of $\{a\}$. Then, by the definition of a dense subset, every point in $X$ is either in $\{a\}$ or a limit point of $\{a\}$ which makes it dense in $X$. Correct reasoning or not?

Comment: Correct. The set $\{a\}$ is dense because every non-empty open set has a non-empty intersection with it. Consequently every set that contains $a$ as an element is dense too.

Comment: @drhab Thanks. Yes, I figured out that every set in my topology is dense.

Comment: Except $\varnothing$.

Comment: @drhab Yes of course. I didn't mean to include that in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Def'n: Any $Y\subset X$ is dense in $X$ iff it has non-empty intersection with every non-empty open subset of $X,$ that is, with every non-empty member of $T.$

Since $\{a\}\in T,$ any dense $Y\subset X$ must necessarily satisfy $Y\cap \{a\} \ne \phi,$ that is, $a\in Y.$ But since every non-empty member of $T$ contains $a,$ it is sufficient that $a\in Y\subset X$ in order that $Y$  be dense in $X.$

So the dense subsets of $X$ are just those that contain $a.$

Assuming that $a,b,c,d,e$ are $5$ different objects, your comment that every set is dense is incorrect. For example $\{b\}$ is not dense. Although every non-empty member of $T$ is dense. But also, for example, $\{a,e\}$ is dense and does not belong to $T.$