# How to find the dense subsets of a topological space

Tags: general-topology

I have the following problem and I'm having trouble putting the theory in practice.

> Let $X = \{ a,b,c,d \}$ with the topology $T = \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{a,b\}, X\}$. Find the subsets of $X$ that are dense in $X$.

Also, if you can help me with some theory for newbies in this subject, it would be awesome. :3

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: I have the theory upfront, but i really can't understand the concepts. I've seen this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1797859/density-in-a-topological-space and i get the fact that if i take let's say M = {b} ⊂ T then the dense subsets are {a,b}, {b,c} and {b,d}. Is it correct?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I know it doesn't that's why I'm here, I'm trying to understand it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $A=\{a,b\}$. Then $A$ is dense in $X$ as any non empty open set intersects $A$. Also you can take another dense set say $\{a,b,c\}$...this is also a dense set since any non empty open set intersects it...In this way u can find out all the dense set in this space.

Comment: And you cannot have any other set be dense, because $\{a\}$ is a nonempty open set in your topology, so any dense set needs a nonempty intersection with $\{a\}$, which means it must contain $a$, the same goes for $\{b\}$. So any dense set must be a superset of $\{a,b\}$, as stated above.

Comment: Let me try to understand what you just said...when you're referring to "non empty open set" you're referring to any set of X with at least 2 elements?

Comment: @TimurMengazi....NO..non empty means "having at least one element"...for example in this case the non empty open sets are precisely $\{a\}$, $\{b\}$, $\{a,b\}$ and $X$

Comment: so if I had T = { O, {b}, {c} , {b,c}, X } then the dense subsets are {b,c} and {b,c,d} and {a,b,c}, {a,b,c,d} bcs they have at least one element when intersected with T?

Comment: @TimurMengazi...Yes..and same logic